# glFrustum on Macbook Pro gives unexpected results

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I'm just setting up a simple renderer using LWJGL 3 and when it runs on my external display it looks like I expect but when resize it on my Macbook it shrinks the viewport. Then if I move the window it fixes it. Here's the code that I run when I init my GL stuff and on window resize.

```
public void resize(int width, int height)
{
    val near = 0.1
    val far = 100.0

    GL11.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();

    float aspect = width / (float)height
    float fov = (float)(45.0 / 360.0 * Math.PI)

    float fH = Math.tan(fov) * near
    float fW = fH * aspect
    GL11.glFrustum(-fW, fW, -fH, fH, near, far);

    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
}
```

Here's what I'm seeing

***Wrong***
[image: Looks Wrong]
***Right***
[image: Looks Right]

If I'm running it on my external display it doesn't change, it's always right.

Comment: Wild guess: something to do with your internal display being a Retina display?  It looks like there's about a factor of 2 discrepancy in the distance from the lower left of the window to the rendered object in the two screen shots.

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/Using_High_DPI_Mode

Comment: I think @JWWalker is right! After you mentioned it I found this in the GLFW documentation: NoteDo not pass the window size to glViewport or other pixel-based OpenGL calls. The window size is in screen coordinates, not pixels. Use theframebuffer size, which is in pixels, for pixel-based calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the size of the frame buffer was the answer here. I create the window with the pixel size the user passes in and then read the frameBuffer size to pass to glViewport.

```
public Window(String title, int width, int height)
{
    _errorCallback = GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err);
    GLFW.glfwSetErrorCallback(_errorCallback);

    if (GLFW.glfwInit() != GLFW.GLFW_TRUE)
    {
        throw IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");
    }

    GLFW.glfwDefaultWindowHints();
    GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW.GLFW_FALSE);
    GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW.GLFW_TRUE);

    _window = GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title ?: "", 0, 0);
    if (_window == 0L)
    {
        throw RuntimeException("Failed to create window");
    }

    // Setup Callbacks

    // Get the resolution of the primary monitor
    GLFWVidMode vidmode = GLFW.glfwGetVideoMode(GLFW.glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());

    // Center our window
    GLFW.glfwSetWindowPos(_window, (vidmode.width() - width) / 2, (vidmode.height() - height) / 2);

    // Make the OpenGL context current
    GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent(_window);

    // Enable v-sync
    GLFW.glfwSwapInterval(1);

    // Make the window visible
    GLFW.glfwShowWindow(_window);
}
```

Then I read the frame buffer size to pass into glViewport and glFrustum.

```
public Vector2 frameBufferSize()
{
    IntBuffer bufferWidth = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(4);
    IntBuffer bufferHeight = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(4);

    GLFW.glfwGetFramebufferSize(_window, bufferWidth, bufferHeight);

    return Vector2(bufferWidth.get(0), bufferHeight.get(0));
}
```